# Best practices in debugging xcode ios 5.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Earlier I'm a .net programmer where debugging is very simple, but now I find difficult in debugging iOS. Can some explain the best and simple way to debug iOS Xcode. Also how to skip between unnecessary files while debugging using shortcut keys?

Comment: There were at least two videos on the subject at last year's WWDC, have you watched those yet? https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use breakpoints to step through code. Also enable a breakpoint that catches all exceptions.  You should probably program in chunks and step through to make sure that chunk works, then repeat.  It is very easy to debug in xcode, using breakpoints and paying attention to the variable values as they come up in the debug window